# Update InfoPath calculated value in real time

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath form that includes some text boxes that have character limits. Below the text box, I have a calculated value to show how many characters are used.

[image: Empty Box]
[image: With some data]

However, the calculated value only gets updated when you click out of the text box. Is there any way to update this value while someone is typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its possible with InfoPath Designer, the reason is that afaik data is only sent back from the field to the data source when the field loses focus. Your calculated field reads from the text fields data source(e.g. my:field1)

I'm not sure if you even could do this easily from code behind for InfoPath either, since you have the same Data Sources to use as in the Designer. You can only access the nodes, and they are still updated when the text field loses focus.